# Get notified when user uploads to an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification of new S3 objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985599/notification-of-new-s3-objects)

We've got an app that stores user data on S3. The part of our app that handles the uploads is decoupled from the part that processes the data. In some cases, the user will be able to upload data directly to S3 without going through our app at all (this may happen if they have their own S3 account and supply us with credentials).

Is it possible to get notified whenever the contents of an S3 bucket change? It would be cool if somehow a message could get sent that says "this file was added/updated/deleted: foo".

Short of that, is there some timestamp somewhere I could poll that would tell the last time the bucket was updated?

If I can't do either of these things, then the only alternative is the crawl the entire bucket and look for changes. This will be slow and expensive.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update 2014-11:**

As Alan Illing points out in the comments, AWS now supports notifications from S3 to SNS, which can be forwarded automatically to SQS: http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-event-notification/

S3 can also send notifications to AWS Lambda to run your own code directly.

**Original response that predicted S3->SNS notifications:**

If Amazon supported this, they would use SNS to send out notifications that an object has been added to a bucket.  However, at the moment, the only bucket event supported by S3 and SNS is to notify you when Amazon S3 detects that it has lost all replicas of a Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) object and can no longer service requests for that object.

Here's the documentation on the SNS events supported by S3:

> http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Based on the way that the documentation is written, it looks like Amazon has ideas for other notification events to add (like perhaps your idea for finding out when new keys have been added).

Given that it isn't supported directly by Amazon, the S3 client that uploads the object to S3 will need to trigger the notification, or you will need to do some sort of polling.

Custom event notification for uploads to S3 could be done using SNS if you like to get near-real-time updates for processing, or it can be done through SQS if you like to let the notifications pile up and process them out of a queue at your own pace.

If you are polling, you could reduce the number of keys you need to request by having the client upload with a prefix of, say, "unprocessed/..." followed by the unique key.  Your polling software can then query just S3 keys starting with that prefix.  When it is ready to process, it could change the key to "processing/..." and then later to "processed/..." or whatever.  Objects in S3 are currently renamed by copy+delete operations performed by S3.

Comment: For smaller volumes of objects the prefixing of the name will work fine. For large volumes of objects, this will actually slow down S3. S3 internally partitions the data based on the bucket name/object key, and keys with the same prefix will most likely end up in the same partition. For high upload throughput you need to keep the object keys changing at the beginning of the string. See this for details: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event.html

Comment: @dlaidlaw: As described by Amazon, it can easily handle bursts of over 100 requests per second even without special prefix distribution of the keys. If you're processing your incoming queue faster than that, you could simply use an "unprocessed" bucket instead of prefix.  However, at that rate you are likely going to be using parallel processors, at which point the suggestion of having a single list of unprocessed files that are polled breaks down (how do you know which thread is processing which file?).

Comment: For very high throughput I write a message to SQS containing the URI to the file in S3. Multiple threads can then process the SQS queue. Yes, there is overhead in writing the SQS message, but it is necessary, and distributed across all the threads sending files to S3. It would be far better if Amazon had a flag to send an SNS message on create in S3, which you could then subscribe an SQS queue to to distribute the load across threads, but until then you have to write your own messages to either SNS or SQS.

Comment: The prefix for newly uploaded is not a bad pragmatic suggestion for many cases (and what happens on a lot of FTP servers that do batch jobs).

Comment: This is now built into S3: http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-event-notification/

Comment: This is a problem I am currently trying to solve. I have checked notifications and they don't seem to trigger when an object is deleted. At the moment I have customers with thousands of objects in buckets to browse and in order to know if anything has changed I need to download every bucket object to check for the change which is painful on data usage. A simple bucket logging mechanism would be nice, something like changes since: date, and then update the model locally.