# How to detect changes in Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification of new S3 objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985599/notification-of-new-s3-objects)
>   [Get notified when user uploads to an S3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674561/get-notified-when-user-uploads-to-an-s3-bucket)

What's the most efficient way to detect changes in Amazon S3? A number of distributed boxes need to synchronize local files with S3. Each box needs to synchronize with a portion of an S3 bucket. Sometimes files get dropped into a bucket from an external source, and so the boxes won't know about it.

I could write a script that continually crawls all files on S3 and notifies the appropriate box when there is a change, but that will be slow and expensive. (There will be millions of files). I thought about enabling logging on the bucket, but it takes a long time for logs to get written, and I would like to get notified of changes fairly quickly.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Join the rest of us in begging Amazon to add SNS notifications when keys change in an S3 bucket.  They do listen to customers and if enough people yell loudly enough...

Comment: So your access to the S3 bucket is not controlled by your code?  Anyone could use any client to drop a file anywhere?  I would address that first...

Answer (score 0):

Amazon provides a means of notifying bucket events (as seen [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)), but the only event currently supported is the *s3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject*.

I am afraid the only ways you can do what you want, today, are by either polling (or crawling, like you said) or modifying the clients who upload files to your bucket(s) (if you are in control of their code) in order to notify your boxes whenever stuff is uploaded/changed.