# Best approach to poll for new S3 objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

So i use S3 as an image store, where images are constantly uploaded to a bucket with various software.

I'm also building a rails app that lets people browse galleries of images on S3, but for performance issues I need to keep a copy of info about the images in the local database, so I don't have to connect to S3's API whenever someones views a gallery.

Now what is the best approach to get notified of new objects on S3 that i don't have info of on my db?

I thought making a worker that constantly fetches a list of all S3 objects and register the ones we don't have, but S3 has a limit of 1000 objects per API request and i couldn't find a way on the [API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) to specify an offset for the next request until all objects are fetched.

Any one has an idea?

*P.S. I'm using [this gem](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) to connect to S3*

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985599/notification-of-new-s3-objects) and in the [S3 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html), S3 does not allow notifications after uploading a new file to S3. With polling you will reach some limits sooner or later.

I would try a different approach. Go to your uploading software and add notifications there. For example you can send a notification to SNS that a new upload is being done. You can subscribe to this SNS queue then with a background task on your servers and fill the necessary infos in your database.

However if you want to go the polling way, have a look at the `Marker` attribute in your results object in the documentation page you linked. Every request returns a marker, and if you give this marker to the next request you will get the next objects that were not available in your first query.

Comment: Thanks, but `marker` returns `nil` and we got thousands of objects, the returned object list size is 1000, meaning there is more results but the marker is nil. weird.